# Symlinks on .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symlink

I want to config .htaccess file for my domain to enable Symlinks and make these:

`public_html/a/folder1/folder2/folder3/` points to `public_html/b/folder1/folder2/`

Plese give me the complete code for these

Comment: you have SSH access to your server?

Answer (score -1):

This will rewrite your URL:

```
RewriteRule ^b/folder1/folder2/$   a/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

if you go to : `example.com/b/folder1/folder2/` it shows you `example.coma/folder1/folder2/folder3/`

**Edit**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTT_HOST}  ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/folder2/folder3/$  http://domain.net/folder1/folder2/
```

Comment: it does;t work with Rewrite rule.. I forgot to specify that a is domain.com and b is domain.net on the same server. I guess that I'll need Symlinks but how ?

Comment: @Symlinks  Sorry, I'm not familiar with symlinks